# problem when deleting template using umbraco

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, umbraco

i have an umbraco page and i linked ascx pages from vs2008.my problem is that i cant delete a template in umbraco named admin.whenever i try to delete it shows message

"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'admin' Key being added: 'admin'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the problem related to your template itself.in your project i think thereare two template aliases with same name "admin". change alias of any one and then try to delete.it will work.

check this tutorial vedios (http://umbraco.com/products/umbracotv)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a template with the same name? Try renaming one maybe? This usually happens because Umbraco doesn't check for duplicates in naming in the first place, but everything must have unique name ...

Answer (score 0):

I did it the hard way! (refid being the 'id' show in the status bar when you select a template in the admin cms window)

```
DELETE FROM  [cmsDocumentType]
WHERE templateNodeId = refid
GO

DELETE FROM [cmsTemplate]
WHERE nodeid  = refid
GO

DELETE FROM [umbracoNode]
WHERE id  = refid
GO
```